# Bounty notification shows 0 days instead of hours

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounty, user-interface

I guess the notification style/verbiage is changed recently but this should show hours instead of 0 days when it reaches the deadline, Is it a bug?

> 0 days left on this bounty. Answers to this question are eligible for a +250 reputation bounty.
>
> [image: post notice screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

This was [previously reported by Martin R on the global Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337013/new-post-notices-rollout-on-stack-overflow/337147#337147).

It has now been fixed:

> [image]

Comment: This doesn't look entirely fixed. The grammatical construction "in 1 minute left on this bounty" does not make any sense.

Comment: Bounty time left is now showing properly, and the grammatical construction should also be better.